# How to filter by date in fuelsdk 1.1.0?

Tags: java, fuel-sdk

Could you help, I don't know how to filter by date on fuel-sdk.

I just want to retrive data after "2015-11-10". I look on Fuel-SDK unit test and not found anything relate to filter by date. I try below code but it does not work.

```
val filter = ETFilter.parse(s"unsubscribedDate >= 2015-11-10}")
val response = client.retrieve(classOf[ETSubscriber], filter)
```

*code in Scala

```
val filter = ETFilter.parse(s"unsubscribedDate >= 2015-11-10") // remove "}"
val response = client.retrieve(classOf[ETSubscriber], filter)
```

I found on other post that ET accect below date format.

Acceptable Date Formats:

Date: "YYYY-MM-DD"
  Date and Time: "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ"
  Date and Time also accepts offset times like YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss+hh:mm and YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss-hh:mm

After fixed my code, I've found Socket Timeout Exception instead.

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

After config timeout to "no timeout". I got

```
com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResponse[
batchResult = com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.ETResult[
    requestId = 49cda6d3-ba76-4b6f-82fb-4529142441cd
    responseCode = Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
    responseMessage = Error: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
]
individualResults = []
moreResults = false
]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are on the right stack exchange board? How does this question related to Salesforce? It would be great if you can expand that in the post.

Comment: Yes, I'm really sure,  Fuel-SDK is SDK of ExactTarget,

Comment: I found my false, It should be '2015-11-10' not '2015-11-10}' but when I input correct filter, I found "Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"